# Gauging a mixture of internal and spacetime symmetries

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, supersymmetry, research-level

Given an internal symmetry, say $U(1)$ or $SU(2)$, I understand how to gauge it, by coupling the conserved current $J_{\mu}$ to a gauge field $A^{\mu}$. Similarly, I understand how to gauge a space-time symmetry, for instance the Poincare group, with the conserved current now the stress tensor, $T_{\mu\nu}$.

However, what happens when your symmetry is a combination of spatial and internal symmetries? For example, what if neither particle number, $n$, nor angular momentum, $l$, are conserved independently, but $l + n$ is? How would such a symmetry be gauged?

I've heard of the Coleman-Mandula theorem that forbids a non-trivial mixture of of space-time and internal symmetries but apparently this relies on having a Lie group structure, while such mixtures are allowed with Super-Lie groups. So I'm wondering if there already exists a way of gauging such symmetries.

Comment: did you read this trick of Wheeler [Dynamical spacetime symmetry](http://arxiv.org/abs/1512.01729) ? very similar technics arise spontaneously with non similar formalisms in Susy and sisters